# Proving sufficient boundary conditions for system of pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a question regarding boundary conditions. In my problem I’m given a system of partial differential equations, and some boundary conditions. The first question asks me to prove that the given boundary conditions are sufficient for solving the problem. How can I formally prove it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What are the PDEs and the boundary conditions?